# Commit blocked by pre-commit hook SVN

Tags: svn, pre-commit

I have subversion on my server, when i try to commit i got error like bellow :

```
error creating module:org.tigris.subversion.javahi.ClientException:svn:
Commit blocked by pre-commit hook(exit code 199) with no output.
svn MERGE of '/svn/mssql/trunk':409 Conflict (http://www.domain.com)
```

Then i try to check on error log inside /var/log/httpd/error_log

i got error like bellow :

```
Could not MERGE resource "/svn/[project name]/!svn/act/8b7476df-3701-0010-a025-c590208c08a0" into  "/svn/[project name]/trunk"

Commit blocked by pre-commit hook (exit code 199) with no output.  [409, #165001]
```

What is that error ?

How to solve this ?

Comment: Resolve the conflict - someone else checked in changes that you're about to step on.  Find out who the other developer is and talk to them.

Comment: Have you updated the working copy before doing the commit?

Comment: I tried to create new repository, when i try to commit project for the first time.i got error it too.

Comment: did you have a custom pre-commit hook script?  I don't believe a new repository, new piece of source code, will cause any problem in commit.

Answer (score 1):

There are two different types of *pre-commit* hooks:

- Server side: This is the standard Unix pre-commit hook. The hook itself lives inside the repository `hooks` directory. If the hook is not executable, or there is no hook script called `pre-commit` the hook does not run.
- TortoiseSVN Client Side Hooks: The hook is on the client and is specific to TortoiseSVN.

When you say *pre-commit hook*, are you talking about the one on the server or the one on your computer? You said you modified the hook by putting `exit 0` in the front.

You don't state what the hook does, or who put it there. This makes it very difficult to determine what is going wrong. There are thousands of Subversion hooks floating around doing various tasks. I have no idea what this one is. Who set up this hook? By default Subversion has no hooks active. Someone must have added it. Who did?

And, why did they put this hook? What is this hook suppose to be accomplishing. Some hooks prevent duplicate files from being added to the repository. Some prevent mismatched casing. Some do security, and some are just jokes.

Post your hook on [Pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and then come back and let us know you've updated it. Let us know who added the hook and why.

Otherwise, there's not much we can do for you.

Comment: This is subversion on my server.I use gforge which include subversion inside.This is pastebin of my pre-commit on http://pastebin.com/XSceFWBV  .I think pre-commit script is automatically generated by subversion.Help me to solve this, thanks

Comment: Your `pre-commit` hook script is calling another script called `pre_commit_checks.php`. This isn't unusual for Subversion. Subversion automatically runs a script called `pre-commit` and you usually modify it to call another script as part of the pre-commit hook itself. Can you post that `pre_commit_checks.php` script to paste bin too? I'd normally say just rename `pre-commit` to something else, but it could be a script that _gforce_ requires in order to work.

Answer (score -2):

I can solve this problem with add new line on pre-commit script with following code :

```
#!/bin/sh
exit 0;
```

After that, i can commit,update,checkout and etc :)

But i must add these line manually on every repository project ? is another ide to overcome this ?

Thanks